# Artifactory plug in

Tags: jenkins, report, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am triggering selenium scripts from Jenkins. At the end of run, I want to share test result.

I have integrated Artifactory plug in so that test result can be placed so that user can access / review the result using Artifactory UI. But I am unable to configure the jenkins job to achieve it. Please help me with the configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [the Generic (a.k.a freestyle) build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds). In this type of build, you can specify which artifacts from your Jenkins workspace should be deployed to Artifactory and under which path.

You can deploy an archived results and then by using [the archive browsing feature](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-AllowContentBrowsing) get a fully working site served from the archive. [Here's an example](http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/org/artifactory/artifactory-papi/%5BRELEASE%5D/artifactory-papi-%5BRELEASE%5D-javadoc.jar!/overview-summary.html) (note the `!` in the url).

Comment: I am having a jenkins project's workspace I want to deploy it into artifactory .                                                        My project name is artifact report and in that I am having test-output under my workspace I want to deploy this into artifactory

Comment: I have problems writing the resolve artifacts and publish artifacts path please do suggest any ideas.The jenkins document on artifact plugin didn't help much

Comment: The first link has an example of how the patterns look like.
If you want us to help you with a concrete example, please post the patterns that you use and the outcome.

Comment: was able to resolve the problem by hardcoding the path and overriding the credentials.Is it possible to specify relative path and passing the credentials

Comment: The pass is relative to the root of the workspace in one side and the root of the repository on the other side.
The credentials are hardcoded in Jenkins conf.